# Selectively copy folders within a directory using text file of known folder names

Tags: batch-file, command-line, windows-7, scripting, batch-processing

I have a directory on my windows box that I want to selectively copy folders and their contents from, onto another directory.  I understand the basic copy commands and for commands of batch scripting, but I'm lost on how to accomplish this one.

I have a large text file containing all the folder names of the directories I wish to copy, is there any way I can pipe in the file names within a for loop of the batch file? I need to do a recursive copy of the directories.

To clarify, I have a text file containing folder names formatted like so:

```
"folder 1"
"folder 2"
"folder 3"
"folder 4"
```

and just from one location to another like `c:\source` to `d:\source_backup`

Comment: Simple enough - show us a sample of your textfile and tell us where you's want the copy to end up.

Answer (score 0):

@echo off

```
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

set "source=c:\somewhere\from"
set "target=c:\somewhere\to"
set "folderList=c:\somewhere\folders.txt"

for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%a in ("%folderList%") do for %%b in (%%a) do (
    if not "%%~b"=="" echo robocopy "%source%\%%~b" "%target%\%%~b" * /e
)
```

Second  for loop (`%%b`) is added to handle possible spaces outside of the quoted folder names. Final copy operation is only echoed to console. If the output is correct, remove `echo` command.